# How to convert long value difference of two time to seconds?

Tags: long-integer

How to convert long value difference of two time to seconds?

Example:

```
Insert Time is 2021-07-28 13:22:05.742906 -> Epoch Value 1627459467906
Update Time is 2021-07-28 13:22:17.779218 -> Epoch Value 1627459516218
Difference between Insert and Update Time is -> 1627459516218 - 1627459467906 = 48312
```

How to convert 48312 to seconds? [Either Manually or using code]

Comment: Your date to Epoch time values look incorrect to me... how did you calculate them?

Comment: So the difference I see in long time 48312 and in time is 12 seconds. But dividing 48312 by 1000 doesnt give 12 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The epoch value is the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970, so the difference is in milliseconds: just divide it by 1000.

Comment: So the difference I see in long time 48312 and in time is 12 seconds. But dividing 48312 by 1000 doesnt give 12 seconds.

Comment: As noted in another comment your epoch values are wrong, and also the difference is wrong, that's why you don't get 12 seconds as result.